# Query a "connection table" to extract selected multiple records

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have two sheets in Google docs. The second one looks like this (simplified):

```
Reference | Comment | Author
-------------------------------
item1     | baz     | John
item2     | bar     | Mike
item1     | foo     | Will
```

I can pull out a single entry using [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheetid", "Sheet2!A3")
```

This would yield `item1` in my example above. So far so good. What I would like to do is to use this sheet as a connection sheet with data for Sheet1. So perhaps using [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), I would like to do something like this (pseudo code obviously) from Sheet1:

```
=QUERY('Sheet2 data from IMPORTRANGE()', "select B, C where A = 'item1'")
```

to get all `Comment` and `Author` from all rows where the reference column equals `item1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to import more than  single cell if to return an array of selected cells and also grant access permission. The syntax requires number rather than letter references, eg:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("key","Sheet2!A1:C4"),"Select Col2, Col3 where Col1= 'item1' ")
```

Comment: Thank you! A follow up question if you don't mind: Is there any way to join this result to print something like `John: baz, Will: foo`?

Comment: @filur: there is.. try: =ArrayFormula(join(", ", query({A2:A,C2:C&": "&B2:B}, "select Col2 where Col1 = 'item1'")))